# Should I process job in batch on aws lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am not sure if i am working correctly with aws lambda.

I have 10 000 emails in plaintext and I need to create screen of every email using google chrome puppeteer.

It is better to spawn 10 000 jobs on lambda? Why/why not?

Is is better to spawn one job peer one task? Why/why not?

It is better to spawn one job for 100 emails? Why/why not?

My problem is, that run of lambda is limited by 15minutes, in 15 minutes I can't process all emails, I need for example 2hours.

Thank you for any hint.

Comment: None is *better* than the other, it depends on what your constraints are. Spawning 10k "jobs" may cost a little bit more, but it will be done a lot faster.

Comment: In my case, I don`t care about time, I can wait for my results.

Comment: Why lambda? Why can't you run the job on EC2 instance or EC2 task? They don't have time limits.

Answer (score 1):

Sticking with Serverless, I would batch your requests and send them to SQS. You would then either consider a lambda trigger or a lambda worker which would poll that SQS. Implementing a DLQ will ensure all your jobs are retained in case a failure occurred. Hardest thing with triggering lambda is it can obliterate a downstream service....having the queue w/ a worker is a nice buffer.